# PushBullet API Auth?

Tags: c#, api, postman

I am trying to use the PushBullet API but I am having some problems with it authenticating my API Key mainly because I am not sure how to properly make a POST to the API.

I tried researching online but I couldn't find what -u means. Does this mean it should go in the header or apart of the data?

```
curl https://api.pushbullet.com/api/pushes \
      -u API_KEY: \
      -d device_iden=u1qSJddxeKwOGuGW \
      -d type=note \
      -d title=Title \
      -d body=Body \
      -X POST
```

I tried to do a Postman like so (I blocked out where the key and device go):
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I needed to add Authorization to the header. Then in the header I used the key as the username. All working now!

Comment: Example: https://github.com/DarkTwisterr/pushbullet/blob/895a8088fe64564e24fa7b61e57c7feff5531086/PushBullet/NewAPI.cs#L95