# Curl to C# user flag

Tags: c#, curl, restsharp

I am attempting to reproduce this Curl call in C# for the Pushbullet API.

```
curl https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
      -u <your_api_key_here>: \
      -d device_iden="<your_device_iden_here>" \
      -d type="note" \
      -d title="Note title" \
      -d body="note body" \
      -X POST
```

Here is my code to replicate it:

```
var response = default(IRestResponse);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/";
request.Resource = "pushes";
var bodyInformation = string.Concat(" { \"", Config.Settings.PushbulletAPIKey,
                        "\": { \"type\":\"note\", \"title\":\"", title, "\", \"body\":\"", message, "\" } }");
request.AddBody(bodyInformation);
response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I send it, it returns this:

```
{"error": {"message": "authentication token is missing or invalid.", "type": "invalid_user"}}
```

For refrence here is the API pages:

https://docs.pushbullet.com/

https://docs.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes

Comment: Im assuming this is a typo? `request.AddBody(bodtInformation);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PushBullet API Auth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739809/pushbullet-api-auth)

Comment: Thats I fixed the typo still a no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the credentials inside the body instead of setting the client's `Authenticator` property to pass them using basic authentication.

The `curl -u` switch uses the username:password credentials for basic authentication to the server. The statement you posted uses the API key as a username and an empty password.

You should use something like:

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(
                               Config.Settings.PushbulletAPIKey, "");
```